# odoo - get value from many2one field

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

My code:

```
class SaleOrder(osv.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    _columns = {
        'xx_delivery_date': fields.date(string='Delivery date'),
        'xx_payment_method': fields.many2one('xx.payment.method',
                                             string='Payment method'),
        'xx_insurance_type': fields.many2one('xx.insurance.type', string='Insurance')
    }

    def _amount_insurance(self, cr, uid, val1, context=None):
        val = 0.0
        insurance_chosen = self.pool.get('xx.insurance.type').browse(cr, uid, insurance_percentage.id,context=context)
        val = val1*insurance_chosen/100
        return val

class InsuranceType(osv.Model):
    _name='xx.insurance.type'

    _columns = {
        'name' : fields.char(size=128, string = 'Name'),
        'sale_ids': fields.one2many('sale.order', 'xx_insurance_type', string = 'Sale orders'),
        'insurance_percentage' : fields.float('Insurance cost in %')
    }
```

I am trying to get the float from the *'insurance_percentage'* field and add this percentage to val1.

At the moment my code results in

```
'Global name insurance_percentage not defined,
```

So I have to somehow tell the function to take the variable from the *InsuranceType* class but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many2one field, we need to first take id of that record and than browse that record with id and take desire value from that.

Try with this code:

```
def _amount_insurance(self, cr, uid, ids, val1, context=None):
    val = 0.0
    for insurance in self.browse(cr, uid, ids,context=context):
        if insurance.xx_insurance_type:
            val = (val1 * (insurance.xx_insurance_type.insurance_percentage/100))
    return val
```