# Odoo : How to import res_partner?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I'd like to modify res_partner in an onchange.
I'm currently doing this:

```
@api.onchange('my_field')
def onchange_model_type(self):
    var = 0
    for res_id in res_partner:
        if self.name == res_id: #name is a many2one in this model which   
                                #leads to res_partern
                                #I check here if res_id is the good partner
            res_id.house = 2 #house is a many2one in res_partner to
                                #a 3rd model.
```

I get :
NameError: global name 'res_partner' is not defined

How do I import res_partner so I don't have this error anymore and I can modify it?

(I already tried `self.name.house = 2` but it don't works, that's why I go straight to res_partner)

Comment: replace `res_partner` with `self.res_partner`

Comment: I get an error:
AttributeError: 'my_model' object has no attribute 'res_partner'

Comment: You have to inherit `res_partner`

Comment: Ok I will try that.
If you find any solution that would allow me to do it without inherit, tell me.
I've noticed in my database that when I inherit, it had every columns of the class in the original res_partner. I'd like that not to happen. More of that I already inherited res_partner in that module and did a many2one to it.

Comment: If you have `many2many` on `res_partner` you can use that field in `for` loop.

Comment: I kind of solved my problem. I used @api.depends in the res partner with a one2many. If someone one day need more info, I detailled it here [http://stackoverflow.com/a/37344100/6345404]